# Вызов функции другого фрейма

Tags: javascript, html

Есть страница с фреймами:

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<TITLE>Тест</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<frameset frameborder = 1 cols = "50%,50%">
    <frame name = "left" src = "left.htm">
    <frame name = "right" src = "right.htm">
</frameset>
</HTML>
```

Файл left.htm

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<TITLE>Левый</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<script language = "JavaScript">
function f()
{
 document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Измененный текст";
}
</script>
<BODY>
    <b id = "txt">Левый</b>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Файл right.htm

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<TITLE>Моя группа</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<b id = "txt">Правый</b>
<input type = "button" value="Tap">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки во фрейме right вызывалась функция f() фрейма left
Я пробовал сделать так

```
<input type = "button" onclick="parent.frames[0].f()>
```

Но это не работает

Answer (score 1):

Уберите пробелы  вокруг `=` HTML-атрибутов и их значений, и будет вам счастье  https://plnkr.co/edit/yWozKyGzo2cq4yYXSzjQ?p=preview

Comment: Не знаю почему, в IE это работает,а в Chrome нет. Хотелось, чтобы в Chrome это работало

Comment: Странно, я как раз через хром его добавлял и все работало. Какую вам ошибку пишет?

Comment: Ошибку никакую не выдает. При нажатии ничего не происходит.

Comment: Сам клик отрабатывает?

Comment: пардон, не сразу заметил: выдает `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick`